# Shelly 2.5 webui not available

Tags: esp8266

I’ve bought a pack of Shelly 2.5 from eBay. It seems they are some kind of special edition since they come with HomeKit support. The HomeKit id is printed on the device. Even though it’s not officially Apple licensed.

I can add them to my phone and they just work fine.

But I don't care about HomeKit and want to add them to my Shelly app.

I’m used to setup Shelly 1pm and plug s. So I tried to access the web UI of the 2.5 but it immediately refuses the connection on HTTP and HTTPS. Ping works though.
The `/ota?url=` command does not work either.

The Manufacturer does not get listed as Shelly in HomeKit. So I assume someone sold me flashed Shelly’s here..

[image]

I want to know if there is a way to flash a new firmware. Maybe per SSH login or something.

Comment: yes, there probably is a way to flash new firmware ... look for a programming connector in the device